# What option we have to build our own MySQL private cloud?

Tags: mysql, cloud

My company has a requirement that we want to build a private DB cloud service for internal use.

Requirements are:

- User can easily request a new mysql instance, and terminate it.
- Each mysql instances are isolated with each other.

One of the solution we have is just using to create different user and schema for each user.  Something similar to what the cPanel is doing.

But I wonder is there better option available?

Honestly, I am don't think putting everybody on the single big MySQL instance is a good idea.

First, we can't do much about resources management.  And I am afraid having a problem in the database (can't boot it up for example) is going to kill everybody.

To minimize the risk of single point of failure, I am looking for something like the Amazon RDS and Azure MySQL.  What we want is very similar to that.

Does anybody know how are they do that?  Is there is open source or commerical version we can buy?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the why it is hard to give you a good answer to your question. If Amazon RDS or Azure MySQL look like a good solution to you, I would suggest using those. Building such a service yourself and making sure it will scale well will probably cost a lot more money.

I mean, sure you could set up Kubernetes or Hashicorp Nomad and deploy containers there but you would need to figure out how these tools work, how to let MySQL run in a scaleable fashion, and build some kind of UI to easily launch and stop MySQL instances.

Comment: We need something internal.  That's company policy and the business decision.  Thanks for your info.